# node express mongodb add data to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need add word to database if that word not exist in my database, if exist show message "word arleady exist, enter another word". Now my code add new word or update if word exist, but i cant to do alert message to show that word arleady exist

```js
router.post('/insert', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.body.title.length == 0) {
        var inputFile = "./k5audios/" + req.body.inputFile;
        var item = {
            title: req.body.inputFile.substring(0, (req.body.inputFile.length - 4)),
            content: inputFile
        }
    } else {
        var item = {
            title: req.body.title.toLowerCase(),
            content: "https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/de/0/" + req.body.title.toLowerCase() + ".mp3"
        }
    }

    mongo.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
       db.collection('words').update(item,
           {$inc: {score: 1}},
           {upsert: true, safe: false},
           function(err,data){
               if (err){
                   console.log(err);
               }else{
                   console.log("score succeded");
               }
           });
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="/insert" method="post">
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="title">New Word</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter new word">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
                                        <input type="file" id="inputFile" name="inputFile">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>

                                </div>

                            </form>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZwoc.png)

Comment: you could use the connect-flash module to solve this problem.

Comment: ok, to show message we can use req.flash, but how to do: if upsert being used then show message if not dont show

Comment: have you tried to check what comes back in the data parameter of the callback function? Sadly I have never used assertion in mongod so I cannot help :(